# How to get data from JSP page to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post, servlet-listeners

I'm new to Servlet functionality. I'm trying to get some data in JSP Form and trying to print it in console using Servlet. But i'm not able to do that.

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>controlServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.selenium8x8.servlet.ControlServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controlServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Startup.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="Startup" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name"/><br>        
        <input type="text" name="group"/>
        <input type="text" name="pass"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">            
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**ControlServlet.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class ControlServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String group = request.getParameter("group");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        System.out.println("Name :"+ name);
        System.out.println("group :"+ group);
        System.out.println("pass :"+ pass);
    }

}
```

After execution, it throws me the following error,

```
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

type Status report

message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

Comment: Check your URL. What address did the request get sent to?

Comment: `<form action="/Startup"` ?

Comment: whats the issue passig data from JSP to Servlet or Page not displayed ??

Comment: I'm getting this error now,  HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL @HussainAkhtarWahid

Comment: I'm getting this error now, HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: @Prasanna : please update the error in the question

Comment: I have updated the question. Kindly have a look sir @HussainAkhtarWahid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Prassana:Please modify your web.xml as below and it should work. I tested your code and its working for me. This will work for both GET and POST.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ControlServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.selenium8x8.servlet.ControlServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ControlServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Startup</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: But I'm getting HTTP Status 404 - /Testing_automation/
type Status report

message /Testing_automation/

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: @Prasanna:Can you give the full url you are trying with?

Comment: which one..? i can't get u

Comment: i'm trying this in apache tomcat

Comment: Ok.How are you trying with apache tomcat?

Comment: @Prasanna: Ok can you stop the tomcat server. Clean build the project and then start the server and try.

Comment: Still i'm facing the same problem

Comment: can you give a clear description of what you are doing to run your code or application or what everit may be. I tested your code and its working fine for me. Here is how am testing it.After starting the tomcat server. Am typing the following URL in the browser. http://localhost:8080/XYZProject/Startup.jsp. where XYZProject is the name of my project and Startup.jsp is your jsp file. If you can give clear description where and when you are getting the error I can help you also try restarting your eclipse after stopping the server.

Answer (score 1):

Change mapping

```
<form action="/Startup" method="post">
```

Step2 : add `ovveride` annotation

```
  @Override
  public  void doPost(HttpServletReques...
```

It is unable to detect your post method and trying to hit `get`  method I guess.

And try to check with get method also once,

```
@Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletReques...
```

Comment: @Prasanna That should not happen. Can you please try like `method="GET"`  and paste the same code in doGet method too and check ?

Comment: That's really weird. Why you mapped `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` ,you given `<url-pattern>/Startup</url-pattern>` right ?

Answer (score 0):

Need to change action in form tag with following

```
 <form action="/Startup" method="post">
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now, HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Answer (score 0):

replace
this : `<form action="Startup"`

by this : `<form action="/Startup"`